# Making Dissect Work In jqt

Tags: j

Per [the wiki](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/Dissect#J8.03_and_later), I've added these lines to "Edit > Configure > User Keys":

```
F2;0;Dissect Line;dissect&.finddissectline_dissect_ 0
F3;0;Dissect Last Error;dissect&.finddissectline_dissect_ 1
F4;0;Dissect Clipboard;dissect&.finddissectline_dissect_ 2
```

However, in the jqt terminal, if I then put my cursor on a line with, eg,

```
3 + 5
```

I get:

```
|value error: finddissectline_dissect_
|       dissect&.finddissectline_dissect_ 0
|[-0]
```

How can I make dissect work?

Comment: Make sure that it is available by using Tools/Package Manager  (listed under debug/dissect). If it doesn't work with the Function Keys after that, you may need to load it from the addons folder. I usually load it with my init for each project. load '/applications/j64-805/addons/debug/dissect/dissect.ijs'

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above the most likely issue is that the addon has not been loaded in your session yet.

To load the dissect addon run the following line in your session:

```
  load 'debug/dissect'
```

Now try to run dissect on a line of code using your `F2`.